# Generating code for text representation of protobuf messages?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Sorry about the somewhat vague question - I have just started exploring `protobuf`, and I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding exactly what can be translated to code.

Let me illustrate with an example - let's say we have this .proto file with "primitive" definitions:

`msgdefs.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto2";
package my_msg;

message MyMsg {
  required string name_id = 1;
  required uint32 num_id = 2;
  optional string data = 3;
}

message MySpecialMessages {
  required string tag = 1;
  repeated MyMsg mymsg = 3;
}
```

... and then, we also have this .proto file, which also defines messages, but using the definitions previously given (in `msgdefs.proto`):

`msglist.proto`:

```protobuf
mymsg {
  name_id: "SPECIAL_MSG_ONE"
  num_id: 101
}
mymsg {
  name_id: "SPECIAL_MSG_TWO"
  num_id: 102
}
```

Essentially, I'd like C++ code generated for `mymsg`s with the given `name_id` and `num_id` "pre-populated"/"hard-coded" (as those represent the valid kinds of messages) - so that I'd only have to deal with populating `data` field of `mymsg` thereafter.

But I'm confused about how this can be achieved (or if the setup above even allows it) - if I try to run `protoc` on the `msgdefs.proto` file, it passes:

```
$ protoc --cpp_out=. msgdefs.proto

$ ls *msgdefs*
msgdefs.pb.cc  msgdefs.pb.h  msgdefs.proto
```

... and the corresponding `.cc`/`.h` files are generated; however if I try the same for `msglist.proto`, it fails:

```
$ protoc --cpp_out=. msglist.proto
[libprotobuf WARNING C:/M/mingw-w64-protobuf/src/protobuf-21.12/src/google/protobuf/compiler/parser.cc:646] No syntax specified for the proto file: msglist.proto. Please use 'syntax = "proto2";' or 'syntax = "proto3";' to specify a syntax version. (Defaulted to proto2 syntax.)
msglist.proto:1:1: Expected top-level statement (e.g. "message").
msglist.proto:5:1: Expected top-level statement (e.g. "message").
```

However, I came up with this Python 3 example, that seems to make the above work:

`test_tb.py`

```py
import sys, os
import time
import subprocess
import google.protobuf
import google.protobuf.text_format

# the below command generates msgdefs_pb2.py (from msgdefs.proto)
CMDS = ["protoc", "--python_out=.", "msgdefs.proto"]
print("Generating msgdefs_pb2.py with: {}".format(" ".join(CMDS)))
subprocess.call(CMDS)

time.sleep(0.5)

import msgdefs_pb2
_myspec_msgs = msgdefs_pb2.MySpecialMessages()
print("_myspec_msgs A:\n{}".format(_myspec_msgs))

_myspec_msgs.Clear()

with open('msglist.proto', encoding="utf-8") as f:
  lines = f.readlines()

google.protobuf.text_format.Merge('\n'.join(lines), _myspec_msgs)

print("_myspec_msgs B:\n{}".format(_myspec_msgs))
```

... and if I run this, I get:

```
$ python3 test_tb.py
Generating msgdefs_pb2.py with: protoc --python_out=. msgdefs.proto
_myspec_msgs A:

_myspec_msgs B:
mymsg {
  name_id: "SPECIAL_MSG_ONE"
  num_id: 101
}
mymsg {
  name_id: "SPECIAL_MSG_TWO"
  num_id: 102
}
```

... so something in here works. I have seen in https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/3.11.2/google/protobuf/text_format.html :

> `google.protobuf.text_format.Merge` ... Parses a text representation of a protocol message into a message.

Ok, so I guess, if `msglist.proto` is inderpreted as a "text representation of a protocol message", then I can use the autogenerated `msgdefs_pb2.py` from `msgdefs.proto` - and then load, that is "merge" the `msglist.proto` into it, and then it works (in the sense that the messages in `msglist.proto` are now visible from Python as part of `msgdefs_pb2.MySpecialMessages()`).

So, I am missing something here - which I could ask for in several ways:

- Can a "text representation of a protocol message" be in some way converted to standalone C++ code for each entry?

  - If not, can I rearrange my definitions somehow, so I avoid the direct use of the "text representation" `msglist.proto` file - and get autogenerated code C++ skeletons for messages of type `MyMsg` and specific `name_id` and `num_id` combos (as it was otherwise given in `msglist.proto`)?
- Can you do a "merge" on the `protoc` command line (say, something like the pseudocode `protoc --cpp_out=. msgdefs.proto --merge msglist.proto`)?